# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable in decorators

Tags: python, python-decorators

```
#decorators in python
users={"ravneet":"elitebook","singh":"punjab"}

def login_required(func):
    def wrapper(username, password, *args, **kwargs):
        if username in users and users[username]==password:
            func(*args,**kwargs)
        else:
            print("not authenticated")
        return wrapper

@login_required
def add(a,b):
    print("a+b: ",a+b)

add("ravneet","elitebook",2,3)
```

Comment: Indentation problem, login_required doesn't return anything. Once you've fixed that, then wrapper doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `return wrapper` has an extra indentation which makes `login_required()` return `None`. Fixed below (and [repl.it link](https://repl.it/repls/AdvancedGruesomeCybernetics#main.py)):

```
def login_required(func):

    def wrapper(username, password, *args, **kwargs):

        if username in users and users[username]==password:

            func(*args,**kwargs)
        else:

            print("not authenticated")
    return wrapper

@login_required    
def add(a,b):    
    print("a+b: ",a+b)

add("ravneet","elitebook",2,3)
```